# Can someone please help me with a good article on CTE. Common table expression

Tags: sql, database, common-table-expression, with-statement, subquery-factoring

can someone provide me with an article on CTE. Article should describe purpose of CTE and where it should be used.

Comment: CTE is TSQL/SQL Server terminology - in Oracle, it's called "Subquery Factoring".  Dunno what/if DB2 or PostgreSQL have different terminology...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out:

- [SQL Server CTE Basics](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/)